# Changing from one coordinate system to another without re doing

Tags: coordinate-system, nigeria

I'm new to this.

Can I change from the Nigeria Mid Belt system to the Nigeria West Belt system easily, or do I need to recreate my project?

Comment: Can you tell which software are you using for your project?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using QGIS it has 'on the fly' CRS (co-ordinate reference system) transformation so you can switch between any projection supported. I find it really great when I use a local projection then want to overlay with openlayers plugin to show google maps.

[image]